# p:fileupload browse only images

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a primefaces file upload

```
<p:fileUpload id="photo" value="#{testController.file}"
                                              mode="simple"
                                              update="messages"
                                              allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>
```

there is no problem in uploading the file, everything works fine. but how could i change that when the user clicks on the browse button, it only browses images files (gif,jpg,png). allowTypes doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: You're saying that when you browse, for some specific folder you can only see gif, jpg or png, how does that relates to allowTypes ?

Comment: i am not sure what allowTypes is for.. What i'm trying to accomplish is. When you browse, other filetypes should not appear but only images. something like `<input type="file" accept="image/*">` of html

Comment: allowTypes facilitates you with ability to restrict only those files to be uploaded whose file extension matches with those you've provided in your regex in allowTypes.

Comment: is there any way to browse only images using p:fileupload?

Comment: I have the same question. Have you solved the problem?